# Does editing someone's paper improve your own writing?

Tags: writing, editors

You get asked to read and edit papers (more or less form the same research area) to become a co-author. The editing requires a lot of rearranging of paragraphs, rewriting sections, new/updated figures, lots of grammar and spelling mistakes, recalculating numbers, and so on.

I am curious to know what your experience is, does your own writing get better from editing papers?

I have heard opinions that it actually decreases your own writing ability - any references for that statement?

Comment: Prima facie, I don't see why it would decrease your ability.

Comment: "You get asked to read and edit papers (more or less form the same research area) to become a co-author". You what now?

Comment: *"I have heard opinions that it actually decreases your own writing ability."* That seems like an incredibly suspicious statement.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: I am doing my Post-Doc, basically just writing papers and helping others with their writing.

Comment: @xLeitix Actually I heard this statement from a senior researcher who is now working as an editor for scientific papers.

Comment: @Michael That seems very shady, bordering on academic dishonesty. To get credit as a coauthor you should be involved in the research, not just editing the paper. Editing should get you an acknowledgment, not coauthor status. What area are you working in?

Comment: @Johanna In my field (engineering) it is quite common to have a team of engineers and researchers working together - and we are usually, to some degree, involved in the research of other team members.  Co-author status and position are often decided based on contribution to the paper. I should have mentioned in the question that I am in the same research group.

Comment: Everybody, can we please not have the same discussion every time publication practices in lab-oriented fields come up? Is it really so hard to accept that what being a co-author means is different in engineering than in, say, maths?